# Understanding how to manage indexes when multiple columns dynamically filtered

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm trying to understand the optimal way to manage indexes for a table that can be filtered in various ways.

Let's say you have a table with 10 columns and millions of rows. You want users to be able to search through this table based on various data points. The column names are:

column1
column2
column3
so on...

The user should be able to search based on any combination of columns.

So 1 request might result in `column1 > 5000 and column3 < 10 order by column4 desc`

Where as another request could be:
`column4 > 50 and column7 = 'test' order by column1 asc`

Various combinations take a significant time to complete, while other combinations take a fraction of a second. Normally I would just add an index, but seem impossible (and pointless) to add indexes for every possible combination of columns.

Is there any "ideal" way to manage table like this? I could add like 50 indexes for the most used combinations, but that feels wrong.

Comment: In addition to the answer from Laurenz, you need to rethink the solution, you cannot satisfy usecase of search by any column with any type of condition by a `rdbms` based solution. You need to think about tools like DW/BI, or 'search' focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no really good way to do that. If you don't restrict the user to entering at least one selective condition, some queries will always be slow.

Your best option is probably to have an index on each column, but that will slow down data modifications considerably.